# Where should the testng.xml file reside in a Java project in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, xml, testing, testng, netbeans-8

I am studying the TestNG [framework](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) with the purpose of using it more specifically with threads, since from what I saw in some websites, it is more efficient in this context (I accept suggestions of other possibilities), but it was not very clear to me where the ".xml" file in question should be inside the project so that I can run it through the IDE itself (in this case Netbeans IDE). Every help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules behind where the testng suite xml file should reside.

If you use a build tool such as `Maven` to manage your project, then you might want to put in your suite xml files under `src/test/resources` folder.

You can put the xml files anywhere within the project to run it from within an IDE.

Comment: Thanks dude! One more question, for the purpose that I said, TestNG really is the best way to test multithreading applications ?

Comment: @Garren - TestNG lets you manage threads in an easier way (if that's what you are after). What this means is that, you can control how your `@Test` methods should run, what should the size of your thread-pool be. Oh btw, please help accept my answer if it resolved your query.